# The icons do not update in the Finder or Get Info Tab

Tags: macos, finder, icon

I recently changed my text editor default from 'Text Wrangler' to 'Sublime Text' but even then all the default icons for the files types such as .js and .php still show TextWrangler default icon. When I open the files, It opens in Sublime Text correctly.

What can I do to fix all these default icons?

[image]

Comment: Here's my answer to similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125402/icons-remains-the-same-after-i-have-changed-the-default-program-for-opening-the/126526#126526 can You check if it works?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I already tried that. It did not work for me

Comment: Reboot solves the problem.

Comment: @fartheraway that solved it

Comment: damn osx caching functions...

Comment: Icon and file associations on the mac always drive me crazy. OS X insists on generating the open with menu automatically, but it's always wrong. Showing duplicates, wrong icons, and applications that I do not ever want to use to open that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for OS X Mavericks.

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user

Running the above command on Terminal will rebuild the LaunchServices DB, and restarting the Mac works.

[Credits for this answer by Mateusz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125402/icons-remains-the-same-after-i-have-changed-the-default-program-for-opening-the/126526#126526)

Answer (score 0):

You may get some mileage out of the following article:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10847?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

In that Info screen, click the Wrangler icon at the top of the page and then <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to cut the incorrect icon. That should restore the 'default' image, which is now Sublime Text.

Comment: The command + x does not cut the icon, although I was able to paste another one but still it only worked for that one file

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, paste the following code and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```sh
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \;
sleep 3
sudo touch /Applications/*
killall Dock; killall Finder
```

Reference: [Clear the icon cache on a Mac when you start seeing generic icons in Finder or the Dock](https://gist.github.com/ismyrnow/e92c6010cda9325b2d8811387a05f224)