# How to set HTML-files icon to default?

Tags: finder, macos, icon

I have a problem with icons in files. Particularly it's only HTML files. I uninstalled Coda 2 app (deleting all relevant info, also clear my cash) and continue to use Sublime Text 3. But I have this (see the screenshot below) and this icons are not updated as my .css or .js files do. How can I fix it?

[image]

Already try this from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148141/the-icons-do-not-update-in-the-finder-or-get-info-tab):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Nothing changes. Maybe because it's especially for OS X Mavericks and I have Yosemite...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The icons do not update in the Finder or Get Info Tab](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148141/the-icons-do-not-update-in-the-finder-or-get-info-tab)

Comment: Already try it - not help, thanks anyway. The top is updated.

Comment: Did you restart ?

Comment: Yeah, sure I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helped, until I uninstalled and re-installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to run

```
rm -r /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.iconservices
rm -r /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.dock.iconcache
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder
qlmanage -r
sudo rm -r /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

and restart.