# Icons Do Not Update After Changing "Open with" Default

Tags: finder, macos, icon, latex

I recently switched from using BaKoMa Tex to Texpad for working with .tex files. After switching the "Open with" default application for all .tex files (which is working fine), I've noticed that the "secondary" file icon is still stuck on the BaKoMa Tex "T" icon and isn't updating. I can manually copy and paste the Texpad icon for each file to solve this problem; however, that is clearly not optimal.
I tried to use the command from a [previous stack exchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148141/the-icons-do-not-update-in-the-finder-or-get-info-tab?lq=1):

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user

But unfortunately, this only cleared the larger Texpad icon that had updated. Attached is a screenshot of the problem. My questions are:

1) How do I get rid of the BaKoMa Tex T secondary icon?
2) How do I restore the Texpad icon to preview (it is currently blank) now that it has been removed?

I am running on OS X El Capitan 10.11, have uninstalled BaKoMa Tex, and have restarted the machine multiple times.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you at least reboot?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times and did not work.