# OS X unable to update outdated app icon in Launchpad

Tags: macos, dock, launchpad

I have an app which is installed in OS X. It needs a certain software patch currently to make it run successfully in the latest OS, and we are sending the patch as a standalone separate app, which when installed, does the necessary things (mainly updating a `Config` file within the `<MyApp>.app` folder in `/Applications`). After this, double clicking the app icon in Finder launches it fine. But when we try to launch it by clicking the icon in the `Launchpad`, it doesn't open. (this is the problem which we are solving, it won't open even from Finder by double clicking without the patch).

So I tried to refresh the Launchpad by these things:

```
rm ~/Library/Application Support/Dock/*.db
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
cd $TMPDIR../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/ && rm db*
```

Nothing works. It still doesn't open. Only upon restarting the Mac does the `Launchpad` click work and the app launches.

Is it possible in any way to fix this without requiring a restart?

OS - Yosemite, El Capitan both.

Comment: Does restarting the LaunchServices help?

Comment: Doesn't `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true;` do that?

Comment: Maybe try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125402/icons-remains-the-same-after-i-have-changed-the-default-program-for-opening-the

Comment: Doesn't work. Same result...

Answer (score 2):

I recently come up with the same question.

```
unlink Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db
touch /Applications/YourAppName.app
killall Dock
```

the `touch(1)` command is very important. things would not work without it.
I think maybe the Dock does not update its db unless the app was updated.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. It should be `~/Library` by the way...

Comment: Huh. Worked for me.