# Icons disappearing from cmd+tab application switcher

Tags: dock, application-switcher

When using my MacBook for a while (Sierra, 10.12.3) then using cmd+tab to switch applications, I sometimes lose application icons. In the screenshot below, it's limited to Chrome but multiple applications will disappear at a time.

I can get the icons back temporarily by restarting or running `killall -KILL Dock` but I'd like a more permanent solution.

[image]

Comment: Already tried [Reset icon cache](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225024/reset-icon-cache-on-macbook)?

Comment: I hadn't tried that but gave it a shot to no avail.

Comment: See if you can isolate it to your account vs system wide issue by attempting to recreate the issue in another user account. I suppose the guest account suffices, but the best test would be to make another "test" account with admin privileged. What results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App icons go missing on MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306923/app-icons-go-missing-on-macbook)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after restarting Dock, I still couldn't see the app icons popping up when I pressed cmd-tab. However, if you could see the Dock restarted after following the instructions to restart it, then the problem might be your external monitor. Unplugging the video cable to my external monitor and plugging it back in fixed it for me.