# App icons go missing on MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, icon

I've been having this problem for a while now and it really starts to bother me. Every once in a while, a lot of my app icons go missing in the dock, launchpad, finder, cmd-tab switcher, just everywhere.

Some pictures:

[image: icons missing from finder]
[image: icons missing from dock]
[image: icons missing from launchpad]

Obviously this is really annoying.
I already tried a lot of stuff to solve it.

- I tried relaunching the Finder
- I tried relaunching the Dock (terminal: killall Dock)
- I tried clearing icon cache

The only way I can (temporarily) solve this by doing the following:

- Reboot, now the icons have reloaded in finder and launchpad, dock icons are still missing
- go to Library/preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
  & delete the file
- open terminal: killall Dock

This way everything is fixed, but I have to rearrange my dock again since I removed the preferences file. It is only a temporary fix though, the issue keeps coming back and I always have to do this, which is very annoying.

Does anyone know what causes this? How could I solve it permanently? It’s really getting frustrating!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This happened to me today (macOS 10.13.1), and the affected icons were all for apps that I'd updated via the App Store over the past couple of weeks (since my last reboot).  Logging out and back had no effect, but a fresh restart restored all the icons.  I'm almost certain that the icons didn't *immediately* become generic after updating, although I wasn't paying attention for that at the time.  Also, when I updated another App Store app today after the restart, the icon didn't become generic.

Comment: For me - setting the icon cache was all I needed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280877/apps-icons-not-appearing

Answer (score 13):

How to Rebuild Launchpad Database in OS X Yosemite (10.10) and Later

1. Go to **Library** folder, which is hidden. To access it, click anywhere on desktop and make sure you see word 'Finder' in the top menu near Apple logo.
2. Press and hold <kbd>alt/option</kbd> key and in the top menu bar select **Go** and finally **Library**.
3. In the **Library** folder, locate and open the **Application Support** folder.
4. In the Application Support folder, locate and open the **Dock** folder.
5. You'll find a number of files in the Dock folder, including one named **desktoppicture.db**, and one or more files starting with a dashed set of capital letters and numbers and ending in .db. An example file name is **FE0131A-54E1-2A8E-B0A0A77CFCA4.db**. Grab all the files in the Dock folder with the dashed set of letters and numbers that end in .db and drag them to the trash or press <kbd>⌘/command</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> keys.
6. Launch **Terminal**, located in the /Applications/Utilities folder.
7. In the Terminal window, enter the following:

   `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`

Launchpad has now been reset. The next time you open Launchpad, the app will rebuild the databases it needs. Launchpad may take a bit longer than usual to launch the first time, and the Launchpad display will now be in its default organization, with Apple apps shown first, and third-party apps next.

Comment: This is a complete solution, tested on High Sierra. Thank you.

Comment: This fixes an intermittent daily problem in HighSierra (10.13.6) where dock stops popping out in the regular desktop, but pops out of hiding only in launchpad.  This is faster than restarting the mac.

Comment: `find "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/Dock" -name "*-*.db" -maxdepth 1 -delete; defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`

Comment: Didn't fix it for me in 10.14.2 :(

Comment: The issue is it's not just the dock. Icons are missing in the Application folder as well. This didn't work for me on mojave

Comment: This did work for me on Mojave. It reset my wallpaper, but it did work.

Comment: On Mojave `10.14.5` I can't get it to work.. But one Thing I noticed is, that If I copy an application from the Applications folder to the Desktop, and open it in the Dock, it shows with an icon, but if I move the copied app into the applications folder again, and open the app, the icon is gone again.. Could this be permission errors from the Applications Folder?

Comment: @Dimser I'm on `10.14.6` and also could not get it to work, however the above plus clearing the icon cache did the trick - `sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store; 
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm -rfv {} \;; 
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rfv {} \;; killall Dock; killall Finder;`

Comment: Note that for apps in the Dock I had to close and relaunch them for the icons to show up. There is some delay while the icon cache is rebuilt as well.

Comment: @doublesharp alas, that just made my problem worse on 10.14.6 :(

Comment: This is complete solution. Tested for Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 6):

Rebuilding the macOS internal launch services database might help.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Once completed, you may need to restart Finder.

Sources:

- [How to fix Mac desktop icons](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/software/operating-systems/how-to-fix-mac-desktop-icons-1298968)
- [Rebuild LaunchServices to Fix Duplicate Entries in OS X’s ‘Open With’ Menu](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/rebuild-launchservices-fix-duplicate-entries-os-xs-open-menu/)
- [Clean out a messy Open With menu in the Finder](https://sixcolors.com/post/2015/10/clean-out-a-messy-open-with-menu-in-the-finder/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. I can't know immediately if it works, since it only happens once in a while, but if it stops happening I'll let you know :)

Comment: Sadly, not fixed. All my icons disappeared again in my launchpad and finder. The dock still looks fine though, so I only needed to reboot.

Comment: Running this command did not help for me.

Answer (score 2):

resetting the icon cache worked for me.

- Launch Terminal
- Enter the following commands, one at a time:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

Use app [Launchpad manager](http://launchpadmanager.com/) app and press Regenereate button on the menu

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by League of Legends.

https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/rA0p1rYx-client-updating-on-mac-high-sierra-messes-up-other-application-icons

Unfortunately, it seems that no solution have been found yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in Terminal; it is working for me:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user;ok
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Especially how it is different from the command in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306931/121968). Did you find it elsewhere on the Internet? Then it would be nice to know the source,

Answer (score -2):

Eventually this is a MacOS software issue. You need to boot the mac into recovery mode and reinstall MacOs to fix the icons. It wont delete any information since its only rebuilding the system files. That should fix the missing icons.

Answer (score -2):

To replace the generic dock icons with the actual application icon, here's what I did:

1. Right click on the generic dock icon
2. Choose Remove from Dock
3. Open the application from the Applications Folder in Finder
4. Drag the application back to the Dock

The new dock icon should be the proper one.