# How to reset file icons associated with default program on El Capitan

Tags: finder, macos, icon, file-extensions

I've uninstalled my former default text editor which I used for many different file formats. Unfortunately the associated icons are not removed automatically. As a result, several file types still use the icon of the program, even though it's not on my machine anymore.

There a several similar questions around here and [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125402/icons-remains-the-same-after-i-have-changed-the-default-program-for-opening-the) seemed to be most promising, but it doesn't work on El Capitan (version 10.11.5). Does anyone how I can achieve this on a current version of Mac OS X?

**EDIT:** After assigning a new default program (no matter if I do that via RCDefaultApp or Finder), the old icon remains. If, for instance, I choose Atom as the new default editor for XML files, the former editor icon (Emacs) is still there.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution? I'm having the same [problem](http://imgur.com/a/tAT2N).

Comment: @Owatch unfortunately no. It is really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in Terminal: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store`
And G'bye atom icon.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. But could you please elaborate on what `com.apple.iconservices.store` exactly does? Are there official references available?

Comment: It's the icon cache, more info here: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/01/30/why-doesnt-that-documents-icon-display-properly-beyond-quicklook/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting a new default to one document, Get Info on one example, select a new app from the 'Open With' drop menu then hit the 'Change all' button below [hidden below drop menu in photo]

[image]

Alternatively, [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) [freeware, old but still works well] can change many aspects of file association.

Comment: Assigning a new default program works, but it's annoying to do that manually.

However, RCDefaultApp looks great! Seems to give the overview I'm looking for. Is there no such service pre-installed (e.g. within system preferences)?

Unfortunately I'm not able to upvote with a repuation less than 15, but I'm gonna checkout RCDefaultApp later and accept the answer if it does what I want.

Comment: Strangely, there's never been a Mac 'service' of any kind that could do this task. Last App I recall that could do it [possibly back in OS 9 days], was Netscape. RCDefaultApp has kind of become the unofficial de-facto standard.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to withdraw accepting your answer (see edit).